# The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string when attempting to connect to Azure SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure

I am connecting to Windows Azure SQL and I get the error `The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string`. This used to work until some thing I am unaware of got changed. I used the default setup when the web application was created by the VS2013 wizard.
I do use entity framework also but I have a different connection string and DBContext for that.

The connection string is DefaultConnection shown below.

> "DefaultConnection" connectionString="data
>   source=tcp:lzol9w71f5.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Eye-Analytics;User
>   ID=Eye-Analytics@lzol9w71f5;Password=[not
>   displayed];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection
>   Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
>
> Line 48:             if (ModelState.IsValid) Line 49:             {
>   Line 50:                 var user = await
>   UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password); Line 51:
>   if (user != null) Line 52:                 {
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Users\grbrand\Documents\Workspaces\EA-Cloud\Eye-Analytics-Azure-Cloud-WebRole\Controllers\AccountController.cs
>   Line: 50
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a
>   ProviderManifestToken string.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +558
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +94
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting
>   provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity
>   Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner
>   exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is
>   correct.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +358

Comment: possible duplicate [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545583/the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the IP of the machine from which you are trying to access the SQL Azure DB is white listed. You can do this from the Azure management portal.