# Uploading Website with Visual Basic Inbuilt .mdf Database in VB.Net (Aspx)

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a website to have a database with it (i.e. Upload the website with the App_Data folder that has Database.mdf in it).

But it cannot connect the attached database using (web.config file)

It works on localhost but it does not work when uploaded, can anyone help me?

**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
  </appSettings>
```

**

Comment: Is you file \Database.mdf available on server? Check in the project directories. Also if you post the error, it will be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: I have editted my post, hope it clears some air. I think the connection data source is no longer valid when uploaded, but i dont know any

Comment: What is the error trace?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687930/db-connection-string-in-web-config-to-use-attached-mdf-database-wont-work You need to find the correct name of the SQL instance on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute **'Data Source'** in ConnectionString notifies SQL Server instance you are using. On Localhost, it will work fine because you have a actual SQL service running there. But when you upload the Site to web server, you must have a SQL server instance running there.

To achieve that, you have to upload your database to server, then you will get server username, password. Now change the connectionstring according to that in web.config and your application will work fine. No need to keep .mdf in App_Data folder.

Comment: where was that? Do i HAVE TO buy a space for database? Is there a free place i could store my database? (im sorry for being newb)

Comment: Don't be sorry for being new. 

And yes, you have to buy a space for database. There are some sites which gives you temporary free storage for testing purpose. Check following site to test it. [Click here](https://somee.com)

Comment: Is someone else hosting your site for you?  If so they should be able to advise you.  If you're hosting it on your own server, you can just use the Express version of SQL Server for small scale development projects.