# Connecting to database using code - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

When I use server explorer in Visual Studio and add a local DB on my D drive, I get a connection string and the connection test is successful.

But when I want to use that connection string like below to attach the database without the wizard and jut by code, I get an error on opening the connection, my connection string is provided below:

```
string coonection_string ="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\\x\book.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

try
{
      SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(coonection_string);
      myconnection.Open();
      MessageBox.Show(" connected");
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
      MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The first thing I would try is getting rid of the double back slash here: `D:\\...`

Comment: Also, can you show us the error message?

Comment: then what error did you get?

Comment: Can you please post the error that you are getting?

Comment: Try to add Database attribute to the connection string ex: Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;

Comment: You are not helping yourself. Saying _I have an error_ and not telling us what is this error is a bit useless. Now you can hope that someone has a crystall ball and can see your monitor from here... (or can you tell us that pesky error message?) By the way, it is `MessageBox.Show(e1.Message)`

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is wrong. Eigher mdf file in your local project or sqlexpres   or you can use a database name in the connection string like

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

or 

Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Check this link.

[DB Connection string in Web.config to use attached .mdf database won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687930/db-connection-string-in-web-config-to-use-attached-mdf-database-wont-work)

Always use Web.config file for connection string and access the entry in code as

```
Dim mWebSvr As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Connectionstring")
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep an @ symbol in-front of the connection string,in C# backslash is a escape character

```
string coonection_string =@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\\x\book.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

else your connection string may not be in correct format

[SqlConnectionStringBuilder.AttachDBFilename Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So, using the @ for escaping what does `@"D:\\x\book.mdf"` become?

Comment: @Alex it needs to be change like this @"D:\x\book.mdf"

Answer (score 1):

Try to put @ before connection string. We use @ before strings to avoid having to escape special characters.

```
string coonection_string =@"Data Source=(LocalDB)  \v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\\x\book.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```