# Open database into application c#

Tags: c#

I have added a SQL Server `.mdf` database file to my C# application, but when I try to connect with this code, the program causes a connection error.

CODE:

```
DataSet data;

string con = "Data Source=dbinterno.mdf;";
string queryString = "Select * FROM Dati";

try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data);
        MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());

        connection.Close();
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("\n Problemi di connessione al database");
}
```

The error is:

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8R4F.png)

Comment: We need more information... What's the error for starters?

Comment: There is no clear information. We don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @trousyt i have insert error image

Comment: @onatm i have insert error image

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery is for Updates, Inserts and Deletes, not SELECT.  Your adapter isn't doing anything.

Comment: did you try to use an absolute mdf file path instead of a relative one?

Comment: if this `string con = "Data Source=dbinterno.mdf;";` is all of your connection string then it's not completed. connection string should be, for example, `Server=.\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=dbinterno;Integrated Security=True` and so on... search google for connection string in mssql server... like error said `the server not found...` because it's not defined in connection string.

Comment: Did you look at [DB Connection string in Web.config to use attached .mdf database won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687930/db-connection-string-in-web-config-to-use-attached-mdf-database-wont-work) or perhaps a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mdf+connection+string&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Comment: btw. if you use `SqlDataAdapter` then you don't need `SqlCommand` at all. Instead `SqlCommand` (which you don't need at all), put your queryString and connection string in `SqlDataAdapter` for example : `string con = "Server=.\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=dbinterno;Integrated Security=True"; string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Dati;"; SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, con);` and then populate `DataSet`.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a couple observations:

1. Your connection string will need to be modified.  Try using 
   `string con = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;";`
   using Windows Authentication or this:
   `string con = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
   Password=myPassword;";` using standard security,  Source: [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).  This should be managed some other way than in code as well.  Desktop applications can be de-compiled, and if the password changes, you would need a rebuild.  In a ASP.NET application, [Microsoft advises](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984237(v=vs.71).aspx) to use a web.config file or in the windows registry using a custom subkey.
2. You will want to use `ExecuteReader()` for a SELECT statement as `ExecuteNonQuery()` will not return a result set.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269651/5811015) that describes the differences in the types of SQL Server methods
3. you don't need `connection.Close();`, the using statement will handle that.

Comment: Your answers under 1. it's better to show user some examples then link to some web site (which "tomorrow" can be "closed"... and, at least, you have to make a effort pointing user to specific link, since "we" talking about mssql server) and it's not *probably* but *have to* and have to very much; under 2. not *probably* but *must* or *have to*, again...